# Sharepoint 2013: Evaluation of ajax GET Requests (XML)

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, xml, sharepoint-2013

I am actually working on a SharePoint 2013 Application (SharePoint Hosted), and want to get the item titles of a SharePoint List. Therefore I am using the HTTP-GET-function of ajax but got now a problem with evalutating the returned XML-Object.

Here’s my code for the ajax request:

```
var requestURL = appweburl + "/_api/lists/getbytitle('Fragenkatalog')/items?$select=Title";

$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: requestURL,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (data) {
            showResult(data);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log("ERROR REST");
        }
    });
```

Got my first Question here, in the beginning I tried to get JSON as a result from the GET Request and therefore I changed the dataType to JSON. After I did this I was always running in the error function. Did I forget something to add there or why it hasn't worked?

The XML document I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<feed xml:base=http://apps-385225078ec0a6.sp.xyz/_api/ xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
        <id>fd01da84-e9ec-4872-842d-d3d29af08119</id>
        <updated>2015-09-24T09:57:46Z</updated>
        <entry m:etag="&quot;1&quot;">
            <id>Web/Lists(guid'86b1cc4b-a52e-4d56-a1be-24a2bccd25c5')/Items(1)</id>
            <category term="SP.Data.FragenkatalogListItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
            <link rel="edit" href="Web/Lists(guid'86b1cc4b-a52e-4d56-a1be-24a2bccd25c5')/Items(1)" />
            <updated>2015-09-24T09:57:46Z</updated>
            <author />
            <content type="application/xml">
                <m:properties>
                    <d:Title>Element 1</d:Title>
                </m:properties>
            </content>
        </entry>
        <entry m:etag="&quot;1&quot;">
            <id>Web/Lists(guid'86b1cc4b-a52e-4d56-a1be-24a2bccd25c5')/Items(2)</id>
            <category term="SP.Data.FragenkatalogListItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
            <link rel="edit" href="Web/Lists(guid'86b1cc4b-a52e-4d56-a1be-24a2bccd25c5')/Items(2)" />
            <updated>2015-09-24T09:57:46Z</updated>
            <author />
            <content type="application/xml">
                <m:properties>
                    <d:Title>Element 2</d:Title>
                </m:properties>
            </content>
        </entry>

    </feed>
```

And here is my result function

```
function showResult(data) {

    $(data).find('entry').each(function () {
        $(this).find("content").each(function () {
            $(this).find("m:properties").each(function () {
                var Titel = $(this).find("d:Title").text();
                console.log(Titel);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Now I want to get the title of each item in my list. 
But the .find always fails when searching for the “m:properties” tag, and thats why I can’t get the information I’m looking for.

Maybe someone of you guys can help me out.

Thanks & kind regards

Sebastian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling the SharePoint REST API, you could control the format of returned data via `Accept` header request. The following example demonstrates how to return data in JSON format as shown on picture below

[image]

**Example 1**

```
var requestUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/items?$select=Title";

function getJson(requestUrl)
{
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: requestUrl,
        dataType: "json",
        headers:  { "Accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose" }
    });   
}


getJson(requestUrl)
.done(function(data){
   //print results
   $.each(data.d.results,function(i,item){
      console.log(item.Title);  
   }); 
});
```

**Example 2**

When `Accept` header is omitted, SharePoint REST returns data in the JSON format shown on picture below ( `minimalmetadata option`)

[image]

```
var requestUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/items?$select=Title";

$.getJSON(requestUrl,function(data){
   //print results
   $.each(data.value,function(i,item){
      console.log(item.Title);  
   }); 
});
```